# reason why it doesn't works on visual 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

I don't think there's a problem with coding grammar or composition. I drew it with my hands and checked it several times and found no particular problem. And I've tried this many times.
I tried to repeat over and over, but it just shuts down immediately without any output on the run window when I use the visual studio 2019 version. I've been Googling several times, but I can't find the solution I want.
Have I reinstall the visual program or have to manipulate extra options?
plz give some solutions

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<stdlib.h>

class Node {
    public:
    int data;
    Node * next;
};
class Stack {
    public:
    Node *top;
    Stack() {
        top->next = NULL;
    }
    void push(int data);
    int pop();
    void show();
};
void Stack::push(int data)
{
    Node *node = new Node;
    node->data = data;
    if (top->next == NULL) {
        node->next = NULL;
        top->next = node;
    }
    else {
        node->next = top->next;
        top->next = node;
    }
}
int Stack::pop()
{
    if (top-> next == NULL) {
        cout << "stack empty" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    Node *temp = new Node;

    temp = top->next;
    int data = temp->data;
    top->next = temp->next;
    delete temp;
    return data;
}

void Stack::show() {
    Node *cur = new Node;
    cur = top-> next;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        cout << cur-> data << "->";
        cur = cur-> next;
    }

}
int main() {
    Stack s;
    s.push(5);
    s.push(1);
    s.push(3);
    s.show();
    cout << endl;
    cout << s.pop() << endl;

    s.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code _as text_. Also, explain "doesn't work"....Visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Your minimal code and errors must be in the question and must be text. Also your link does not work for me.

Comment: On the other hand, the link might work for me, but there's no way on God's Green Earth am I risking infection clicking it to find out.

Comment: It might be that you have found a bug in Visual Studio and you need to update. It might that your program has a bug. Which do you think is the more likely? Since you haven't posted the code and your link doesn't work for me I have no idea

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I fix my problem plz take a look

Comment: @john I updata the latest version, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your issue is that `top` is an uninitialized pointer. So in the constructor, `top->next = NULL;` will cause an error because `top` does not point anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor

```
Stack() {
    top->next = NULL;
}
```

`top` has never been given a value, so `top->next` is an error.

Looks to me that most of your code would be fixed if you replaced `top->next` with `top` throughout.

There's another error here

```
void Stack::show() {
    Node *cur = new Node;
    cur = top-> next;
```

You assign `cur` to a new node and then you forget about that and assign it to something else on the very next line. Just do this

```
void Stack::show() {
    Node *cur = top-> next;
```

(but `top-> next` should really just be `top` as explained above).

and the same error here

```
Node *temp = new Node;

temp = top->next;
```

why assign a new node to `temp` if on the very next line you assign something else to `temp`?

Here's your code will all the bugs fixed (I think)

```
class Stack {
    public:
    Node *top;
    Stack() {
        top = NULL;
    }
    void push(int data);
    int pop();
    void show();
};
void Stack::push(int data)
{
    Node *node = new Node;
    node->data = data;
    node->next = top;
    top = node;
}
int Stack::pop()
{
    if (top == NULL) {
        cout << "stack empty" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    Node *temp = top;
    int data = temp->data;
    top = temp->next;
    delete temp;
    return data;
}

void Stack::show() {
    Node *cur = top;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        cout << cur-> data << "->";
        cur = cur-> next;
    }

}
```